# How to append " _INC" (String) to the end of every element in List?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to append "_INC" to every element in a list. The List contents look like this:

```
public final static List<String> PROVIDERS = Arrays.asList("asco_genes", "pubmed_oa_genes", "wiley_journals_genes", "mms_genes", "elsevier_genes", "medline_genes",
            "asco_drugs", "pubmed_oa_drugs", "wiley_journals_drugs", "mms_drugs", "elsevier_drugs", "medline_drugs", "aaas_genes", "aaas_drugs", "aacr_genes","aacr_drugs",
            "springer_nature_genes", "springer_nature_drugs");
```

After the programming logic the list should look like this:

```
 public final static List<String> PROVIDERS = Arrays.asList("asco_genes_INC", "pubmed_oa_genes_INC", "wiley_journals_genes_INC", "mms_genes_INC", "elsevier_genes_INC", "medline_genes_INC",
                "asco_drugs_INC", "pubmed_oa_drugs_INC", "wiley_journals_drugs_INC", "mms_drugs_INC", "elsevier_drugs_INC", "medline_drugs_INC", "aaas_genes_INC", "aaas_drugs_INC", "aacr_genes_INC","aacr_drugs_INC",
                "springer_nature_genes_INC", "springer_nature_drugs_INC");
```

I've looked at using string builder and using an character array to accomplish task but they seem sort of complex. I'm wondering if java has any predefined libraries that can make this easier.

Comment: If it's always just two strings, use +

Comment: `static { for (ListIterator<String> iter = PROVIDERS.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); iter.set(iter.next() + "_INC")); }` (for all Java versions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java 8+ you can create a `stream` and add `"_INC"` and then collect it to a `List`:

```
List<String> list = Stream.of("asco_genes", "pubmed_oa_genes", "wiley_journals_genes", "mms_genes", "elsevier_genes", "medline_genes",
        "asco_drugs", "pubmed_oa_drugs", "wiley_journals_drugs", "mms_drugs", "elsevier_drugs", "medline_drugs", "aaas_genes", "aaas_drugs", "aacr_genes","aacr_drugs",
        "springer_nature_genes", "springer_nature_drugs")
                          .map(e -> e + "_INC")
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which produces:

```
mms_genes_INC
elsevier_genes_INC
medline_genes_INC
asco_drugs_INC
pubmed_oa_drugs_INC
wiley_journals_drugs_INC
mms_drugs_INC
elsevier_drugs_INC
medline_drugs_INC
aaas_genes_INC
aaas_drugs_INC
aacr_genes_INC
aacr_drugs_INC
springer_nature_genes_INC
springer_nature_drugs_INC
```

Comment: Instead of `Arrays.asList(...).stream()` use `Stream.of(...)`

Answer (score 3):

You really neither need a stream nor a `for` loop (provided you use Java 8 or later; using your declaration from the question):

```
    PROVIDERS.replaceAll(s -> s + "_INC");
```

Result:

> ```
> asco_genes_INC
> pubmed_oa_genes_INC
> wiley_journals_genes_INC
> mms_genes_INC
> elsevier_genes_INC
> medline_genes_INC
> asco_drugs_INC
> pubmed_oa_drugs_INC
> wiley_journals_drugs_INC
> mms_drugs_INC
> elsevier_drugs_INC
> medline_drugs_INC
> aaas_genes_INC
> aaas_drugs_INC
> aacr_genes_INC
> aacr_drugs_INC
> springer_nature_genes_INC
> springer_nature_drugs_INC
> ```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, if you don't have access to lambdas, and *if the list is mutable and you don't want to create a new list* but replace all elements in the list with new `String` objects:

```
List<String> lst = Arrays.asList(...);
int n = lst.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // Or lst.size() if you fear concurrent accesses
    lst.set(i, lst.get(i)+"_INC"); // Or lst.get(i).concat("_INC")
}
```

Two sides notes:

- `String` is immutable so you can't change its content
- there is no runtime penalty if the `List` implementation has random-access (e.g. `ArrayList`), but it works sub-optimally for non-random access implementations (e.g. `LinkedList`)